# How to display the title in header corresponding to the date selected in ionic?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, cordova-3

How I can display the title in header coresponding with simultaneously  to the date selected in ionic?

Its my template html for header:

```
<ion-view cache-view="false" title="{{ currentDate | date:'MMM  dd, yyyy'      }}">
<ion-nav-buttons side="secondary">
    <button class="button-icon icon ion-calendar assertive" ng-click="datePicker()">  </button>
 </ion-nav-buttons>
  //Input your content
  </ion-view>
```

My controller.js

```
$scope.currentDate = new Date();

$scope.date = [];
$scope.datePicker =function($event) {
        var options = {
            date: new Date(),
            mode: 'date'
        };
        datePicker.show(options, function(date){
            if(date != 'Invalid Date') {
                console.log("Date came" + date);
               $scope.currentDate  = date;
                console.log($scope.date);
            } else {
               $scope.currentDate  = date;
                console.log(date);
            }

        });
        $event.stopPropagation();  

        }
```

For date time picker, I am using [this plugin](https://github.com/VitaliiBlagodir/cordova-plugin-datepicker).

Thanks before!

Comment: In what format do you get the date from the plugin?

Comment: @emre yyyy-dd-mm hh:mm:ss

Comment: It may return a string and you may have to convert it to date object